# Android recognize cell phone with keyboard or not?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my android app, I want to detect the user's device if the device has keyboard(like motorola milestone) and then show corresponding user interface. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html

public int keyboard

The kind of keyboard attached to the device. One of: KEYBOARD_NOKEYS, KEYBOARD_QWERTY, KEYBOARD_12KEY.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if there is a mechanism to allow detection of physical keyboard?

yes, Android does have the capability to notify applications of a keyboard open/close event.

You'll have to add detection of configuration changes to your activities. I believe there is a notification that is posted to the activity currently displayed that will indicate the keyboard state (or device configuration change).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html might give more insight in to what you're looking for.